# How can I determine if an element has been configured with a dialog?

Tags: jquery

Here is a sample of what I am trying to do.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      function doOpen() {
        if ($('#dialog-modal').dialog('widget') == '')
          document.getElementById('#dialog-modal').style.display = 'block';
        else    
          $('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');
      }

      function doClose() {
        if ($('#dialog-modal').dialog('widget') == '')
          document.getElementById('#dialog-modal').style.display = 'none';
        else
          $('#dialog-modal').dialog('close');
      }     

      function doAttach() {    
        $('#dialog-modal').dialog({
          width: 'auto',
          height: 'auto',
          title: 'Popup Dialog',
          autoOpen: false,
          resizable: false,
          modal: true
        });

        document.getElementById('dialog-modal').style.display = 'block';
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="Show" value="Open" onclick="doOpen();" />
<input type="button" id="Attach" value="Attach" onclick="doAttach();" />

<div id="dialog-modal" style="display:none">
Show this in a model dialog window<br />
<input type="button" id="Close" value="Close" onclick="doClose()" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I click “Attach” before doing anything else, the dialog shows up just fine.  But if I click “Open” first, then I get the error.  I need to know what this line should be to find out if dialog-modal has been attached to a dialog

```
if ($('#dialog-modal').dialog('widget') == '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell what you're trying to do, but you could use data() to see if a dialog has been attached.

```
if ($('#dialog-modal').data('uiDialog')) {
  alert('dialog attached');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the plugin add some class and data in the target html element. You need to find out what class and data they are adding than you can keep it on condition 
like

```
if($('selector').hasClass('classAdded')){
//do something
}
```

Or

```
if($('selector').data('dataKey')){
//do something
}
```

For class you can simply see on firebug screen or other screen. 
To get what data they are assigning use

```
alert(JSON.stringify($(selector).data()));
```